# Selecting the top 5 in a column with duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written a query that gives me a list of data and I need to select the top 5 pieces of data. For example

```
Num  Name
5    a
4    b
4    c
2    d
1    e
1    f
1    g
0    h
```

However if I simply use LIMIT 5, this leaves out data points with name f and g. How would I be able to select from a-h. This is just an example data piece. My actual data contains a lot more rows so I can simply just exclude the bottom row. 
EDIT sorry when i said top 5 i meant top 5 Num entries. so 5, 4 ,2 ,1,0 but 1 has duplicates so I wanted to select all of these duplicates

Comment: How does your query look like?

Comment: I'm confused. What is your full condition for selecting data? LIMIT 5 will return 5 rows. What do you mean you also want to select from a-h? That is, obviously, more than 5 rows.

Comment: your question is not very clear.What does top 5 exactly mean?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: It still isn't clear.

Comment: Top 5 `Num` entries ... `5,4,2,1` ... these are 4 entries, not 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT t1.Num, t1.Name, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.Num) AS seq
    FROM yourTable t1
        LEFT JOIN
        yourTable t2
        ON t1.Num <= t2.Num
    GROUP BY t1.Num, t1.Name) dt
WHERE (seq <= 5);
```

[[SQL Fiddle Demo]](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eba96/1)

Comment: Unfortunately this query is slow for big tables. If the table has n rows, there are n*n+1 rows resulting from the join, prior to the count.

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate via adding a new field with an incremental row number within your SQL logic as following:

```
Feeds  Num  Name
  1     5    a
  2     4    b
  2     4    c
  3     2    d
  4     1    e
  4     1    f
  4     1    g
  5     0    h
```

and then limit the result by the required rank (in your case 5). Following is the SQL for your reference:

```
SELECT num, name from (
SELECT @row_number:=CASE WHEN @num=num 
THEN @row_number ELSE @row_number+1 END AS feeds,@num:=num AS num, name
FROM table1, (SELECT @row_number:=0,@num:='') AS t
ORDER BY num desc 
  )t1
  WHERE feeds <= 5
```

[SQL-fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e66c7/20)

Comment: This solution is much more efficient on big tables than the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

Check this query

```
SELECT 
t1.Num, 
t1.Name,
FIND_IN_SET(t1.Num, SUBSTRING_INDEX(
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(t2.Num ) ORDER BY t2.Num DESC), ',', 5)
) AS Ord
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2 ON(t2.Num IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY t1.Name
ORDER BY t1.Num ASC
```