# MySQL : Top K with duplicates

Tags: mysql

Ex: Lets say I have 10 categories (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j) and the counts of products in each category are : (5,6,10,4,10,4,6,10,10,4). Now if I want to find the top 5 categories with max products:

```
c - 10
e - 10
h - 10
i - 10
(b,g) - 6 (sometimes it will be b and sometimes it will be g, if I use the LIMIT 5 option.)
```

What I need: If there are categories with counts same and there are no fixed rule to return which category, then I want the sql query to return all such categories. In the above example, I want the sql query to return 6 rows. In case if all categories have 10 products, then querying for top 5, I need 10 rows to be returned.

I saw this question : [Selecting the top 5 in a column with duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33061894/selecting-the-top-5-in-a-column-with-duplicates). But it has a different requirement.

Comment: how about you post some relevant data and the query that you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with an inner select. First get the counts of the top k categories, then get all categories that have those counts.

```
Select cat_count, category from 
    (select count(category) as top_count
    from products group by category order by count(category) desc limit 5)
as t1 inner join 
    (select count(category) as cat_count, category 
    from products group by category) as t2 on t1.top_count = t2.cat_count
```

Or written differently :

```
select count(category), category 
from products 
group by category
having count(category) in 
    (select count(category) as top_count
    from products 
    group by category
    order by count(category) desc limit 5)
```

Comment: This will probably work (I am referring to your 2. version), but you should leave out the `distinct` in the subquery, otherwise you will also get the lines for counts 4 and 5.